# Twitter API 1.1 parsing JSON data and getting twitter links

Tags: php, json, twitter

Am using the connection code from: http://blog.jacobemerick.com/web-development/parsing-twitter-feeds-with-php/ Which is awesome.  Am connecting to the 1.1 API wonderfully.

Issue comes into play when parsing the returned JSON data.

One recommendation is:

```
foreach($response as $tweet)
{
    foreach($tweet->entities->urls as $urls_object)
    {
    $search = "{$urls_object->url}";
    $replace = "<a href=\"{$urls_object->url}\" title=\"{$urls_object->expanded_url}\">{$urls_object->display_url}</a>";
    $text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
    }
}
```

This is NOT replacing the text and cannot see why.  Cannot seem to get a grip on or access the supposedly replaced data.

Edit - Followup:

Was attempting to use the replaced data via:
    echo $tweet->entities->urls;

Maybe my understanding of how to use the replaced data is not accurate?

Comment: Where is text set? Did you mean to pass in response as the third param in str_replace?

Comment: I believe that this is supposed to be:  $tweet->text   Have attempted this several ways and am still missing it. MY assumption was that the JSON data would be overwritten with the new value.  Is this not the case?